Is it possible to have full sql queries in the stack trace?
I wasn't able to locate a solution to this online, google was not being my friend today. Recently we did a PHP upgrade to 8.3 on our webserver at work, from PHP 5.6.12, which was quite a heavy lift. Lots of things were deprecated so we are now going through the php error log and fixing up little issues from dividebyzero, int to float, etc..
One thing I've noticed is that the php error_log file specified in the php.ini logs some great information, however, the query that causes a problem is normally cut off and not fully shown. Is there a way to configure the php.ini file that the full query is written to the log file?
Currently an output will look something like:
#0 E:\BOTServer\bot\phpscripts\usersearch.red2.php(18): mysqli->query('SELECT *,REPLAC...')


Have you tried setting log_errors_max_len? That's supposed to default to 1024 bytes, but it looks as if your sample line is already shorter unless it was edited for the forum. Setting that value to zero apparently means "no limit". As you know which line of code the error occurs on, that surely points you to where to look. Or do you just want to see any variables you've put in the query, if you're not using Prepared Statements?

"Is there a way to configure the php.ini file that the full query is written to the log file" - Just to be clear, this is logging PHP code, not MySQL. The PHP just code happens to have a string in it that is being passed to the database. This might be obvious, but also might be why your searches were failing today, too.

If you go and look at line 18 of usersearch.red2.php you'll be able to see what the rest of the line, and the SQL query within it, look like. The error message just summarises it briefly, but the line number tells you where to go and see the original.

Yes, I do know which line to begin looking for the code, however like @droopsnoot mentioned we have alot of variables being fed into our queries so being able to see what is being fed into the query helps alot more to figure out the issue as when you go to the line # and find the query itself it has variables mixed in the queries.

Well your query should be parameterised, right? So the SQL statement itself should never change, and you'd only see the parameter placeholders if you log the string. (If you're not parameterising your queries, you have a big security hole to fix!). In that scenario you'd need to separately log the actual variables being set as parameters to the query. MySQL itself can also log incoming queries and so on, separately from PHP

Looks like log_errors_max_len was removed >= 8.0 of php, I'm curious does zend.exception_string_param_max_len replace this now?

you can always write your own log files without any limitations. you can even pick up sql queries specifically and log only them instead of entire trace.

From your description it sounds like the issue isn't that you can't see SQL in logs, but that you are vulnerable to SQL injection. Replace your mysqli_query calls with actual paramterized queries (you can do it with mysqli_execute_query() and you won't need longer error log messages.
